# How to update UI after PopupMenuItem is dismissed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatables, statefulwidget, paginateddatatable

I have an issue with updating the UI right after popupmenu is dismissed. The item being clicked actually is being deleted but updating it is the problem. I understand that I am calling this method from an unstatefull class that extends DatatableSource.

Here is the code:
1: Datasource

```
class ResultDataSource extends  DataTableSource{
  //Dependency injection
  var brandsController = BrandsController(BrandsRepository());
  ResultDataSource({
    @required List<Result> resultData,
    @required this.onRowSelect,
  })  : _resultData = resultData,
        assert(resultData != null);

  final List<Result> _resultData;
  final OnRowSelect onRowSelect;



  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);

    if (index >= _resultData.length) {
      return null;
    }
    final _result = _resultData[index];

    return DataRow.byIndex(

      index: index, // DONT MISS THIS
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('${_result.name}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: secondaryColor))),
        DataCell(Text('${_result.country}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, color: secondaryColor))),
        DataCell(Text('${_result.isActive.toString() == "true" ? "Active" : "Inactive"}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: primaryColor),)),

        DataCell(
           FutureBuilder<List<Result>>(
                  future: brandsController.fetchBrandList(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    return PopupMenuButton(
                      elevation: 20.0,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.more_horiz,
                        color: secondaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context) =>[
                        PopupMenuItem(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/view.svg", height: 18.0,color: Colors.blueGrey, ),
                              SizedBox(width:10.0),
                              Text("View Details", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          value: 1,
                        ),
                        PopupMenuItem(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/repeat.svg", height: 18.0,color: Colors.blueGrey, ),
                              SizedBox(width:10.0),
                              Text("Orders", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          value: 2,
                        ),
                        PopupMenuItem(
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/activities.svg", height: 18.0,color: Colors.blueGrey, ),
                              SizedBox(width:10.0),
                              Text("Activities", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                            ],
                          ),
                          value: 3,
                        ),

                        PopupMenuItem(
                          onTap: ()  {
                            //Here is the delete functionality
                            brandsController.deleteBrand(_result.id.toString());
                          },
                          child:Row(
                                children: [
                                  SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/garbage.svg", height: 18.0,color: Colors.blueGrey, ),
                                  SizedBox(width:10.0),
                                  Text("Delete", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                                ],
                              ),
                          value: 4,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
            )
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  @override
  int get rowCount => _resultData.length;
  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

2: Code from Statefull widget class

```
ListView(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            children: [
                              Theme(

                                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                  dividerColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade100.withOpacity(0.4),
                                ),
                                child: PaginatedDataTable(
                                  rowsPerPage: snapshot.data.length ?? 1,
                                  showCheckboxColumn: true,
                                  dataRowHeight: 60,
                                  columns: [
                                    DataColumn(label: Text(
                                      "Name",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13.5,
                                          color: secondaryColor.withOpacity(0.4)),
                                    ),),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text(
                                      "Country",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13.5,
                                          color: secondaryColor.withOpacity(0.4)),
                                    ),),
                                    DataColumn(label: Text(
                                      "Status",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 13.5,
                                          color: secondaryColor.withOpacity(0.4)),
                                    ),),
                                    DataColumn(label: PopupMenuButton(
                                      elevation: 20.0,
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.more_horiz,
                                        color: secondaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      ),
                                      itemBuilder: (context) =>
                                      [
                                        PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                                "assets/icons/view.svg", height: 18.0,
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey,),
                                              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                              Text("View Details", style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          value: 1,
                                        ),
                                        PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                                "assets/icons/repeat.svg", height: 18.0,
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey,),
                                              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                              Text("Orders", style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          value: 2,
                                        ),
                                        PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                                "assets/icons/activities.svg", height: 18.0,
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey,),
                                              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                              Text("Activities", style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          value: 3,
                                        ),
                                        PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: [
                                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                                "assets/icons/garbage.svg", height: 18.0,
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey,),
                                              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                                              Text("Delete", style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 13.0),)
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          value: 4,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ],
                                  source: ResultDataSource(
                                    onRowSelect: (index) => () {},
                                    resultData: snapshot.data,

                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It depends on your state management choice. If I were using providing for example, I would notify listeners, and my `Consumer` in that page would be rebuilt reflecting my new state. Just relying on the native flutter framework tools will only get you so far.

Comment: @moneeralhashim Let me try implementing that